# how to change Android Studio emulator settings while "launch in a tool window" is active in Settings?

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

I can not find emulator settings if emulator tool windows is marked.
I want this settings:

[image]

while "launch in a tool window" is active in Settings:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As stated in [the official Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator#limitations):

> Currently, you can't use the emulator's extended controls when it's
> running in a tool window. If your development workflow depends heavily
> on the extended controls, continue to use the Android Emulator as a
> standalone application. In addition, certain virtual devices—such as
> Android TV and foldable devices—can't be run in Android Studio because
> they have specialized UI requirements or important functions in the
> extended controls.